# How do I benchmark and profile IO bound Perl web application under heavy load?

Tags: perl, performance, web-applications, profiling, benchmarking

How do I benchmark (compare two different implementations) and profile (find performance bottlenecks in an implementation) behavior of a web application (in Perl) under heavy load?  This webapp is (supposedly) IO bound rather than CPU bound.

I'd like to compare proposed implementation (proposed improvement) with current solution, either on real load but minimizing eventual performance hit (perhaps two different implementations on different servers behind load balancer), or replay / simulate load on a new implementation, or simulate heavy IO usage.

I'd like also profile CPU and IO bottlenecks in proposed implemetation, but testing behavior under heavy load.

The OS is Linux, web server is Apache.

---

The same question is posted on ServerFault: [How do I benchmark and profile IO bound Perl web application under heavy load?](https://serverfault.com/questions/185568/how-do-i-benchmark-and-profile-io-bound-perl-web-application-under-heavy-load)

I think the answer here can be about benchmarking and profiling web application written in Perl, and perhaps also about replicating realistic load conditions, or finding measure / benchmark which would predict which implementation would perform better under IO bound conditions under heavy load.

Comment: Plain CGI and FastCGI (via CGI.pm and CGI::Fast), mod_perl deployment via ModPerl::Registry, PSGI deployment via wraper using Plack::App::WrapCGI

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an OS- or driver-agnostic way of benching this.. you might find some tools specific to your persistent storage drivers that can tell you usage statistics, e.g. bytes transferred, throughput etc, that you can compare for your different implementations.  You might also want to throw this question out on http://serverfault.com to see what disk usage utilities exist for Linux? It's not really a Perl question so much as system administration.

Comment: http://www.perl.org/about/whitepapers/perl-profiling.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use Munin ( http://munin-monitoring.org/ ).

It has tons of plugins to see how a system behaves: cpu, i/o, memory, network usage, mysql transactions, ...almost everything.

Comment: Not exactly answer I wanted to see, but it will be useful.

Answer (score -1):

You could create some tests using the [Benchmark](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.2/lib/Benchmark.pm) module.  It has functions specifically for comparing two implementations of the same functionality.  While it doesn't quite handle simulating load levels for you, it would make it a lot easier to do.

Comment: I know about Benchmark module; the problem is either simulating I/O pressure situation, or using it on live-data like input, or using it in web app.